# How can I substitute into this shell command?

Tags: shell, files, find

I have a `find` command that I want to substitute a list of GIDs into.

Here's the command:

`find / -follow \( -group 39 -o -acl_group 39 \) -exec ls -ln {} \; 2> $HOME/error.39.log 1> $HOME/results.39.log`

I also have a file with the contents:

```
3  
100005  
21  
7
```

How can I substitute each entry in the file into the `find` command in turn so that a separate output and error file is created for each?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to invoke `ls` to get at the `stat` information, `find` already did that. Use something like this instead (same output as `ls -ln`):

```
find -follow \( -group 39 -o -acl_group 39 \) -printf '%M  %n %U %G %s %Cb %Cd %CH:%CM %p\n'
```

See section 3.2.2 of the GNU find manual for more on the format directives.

#### Edit

To apply this to multiple group ids from a file:

```
while read; do
  find -follow \( -group $REPLY -o -acl_group $REPLY \) \
    -printf '%M  %n %U %G %s %Cb %Cd %CH:%CM %p\n'      \
    1> $HOME/results.$REPLY.log                         \
    2> $HOME/error.$REPLY.log
done < group_id_file
```

Comment: Well the key part of the problem I was trying to solve was the substitution of the GID from a file into the appropriate part of the command

Comment: You could add a while loop around `find` and use redirect `<` to get the IDs into `$REPLY`. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Avoiding `-exec` will have great efficiency benefits if you have many files. You avoid multiple `stat` calls but more importantly you do not `fork` for every match.

Answer (score 2):

What about a for statement? something like:

```
for f in `cat file_with_entries`; do
    find -follow \( -group $f -o -acl_group $f \) -exec ls -ln {} \; 2> $HOME/error.$f.log 1> $HOME/results.$f.log
done
```